# Link doesnt work in FF

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, coldfusion, hyperlink

Here is the link:

```
<a href="javascript://" onClick="print_gonder();"><img src="/images/print.gif" title="Gönder" border="0"></a>
```

and its function print_gonder:

```
function print_gonder()
{
    var satirsayisi=document.list_basketww.row_count.value; 
    var amnt=new Array(satirsayisi);
    var prc=new Array(satirsayisi);
    var kdv=new Array(satirsayisi);
    var kon=new Array(satirsayisi);
    var yap=new Array(satirsayisi);
    var ona=new Array(satirsayisi);
    var ode=new Array(satirsayisi);
    var tes=new Array(satirsayisi);
    for (i=0; i<satirsayisi; i++)
    {   
        amnt[i]=eval("document.getElementById('amount" + (i+1) + "')").value;
        prc[i]=filterNum(eval("document.getElementById('price" + (i+1) + "')").value);
        kdv[i]=eval("document.getElementById('tax_dif" + (i+1) + "')").value;
        kon=eval("document.getElementById('konu')").value;
        yap=eval("document.getElementById('yapan')").value;
        ona=eval("document.getElementById('onay')").value;
        ode=eval("document.getElementById('odeme')").value;
        tes=eval("document.getElementById('teslim')").value;
    }
    windowopen('<cfoutput>#request.self#?fuseaction=objects2.popup_sale_propose&print=true#page_code#&amnt='+amnt+'&prc='+prc+'&kdv='+kdv+'&konu='+kon+'&yapan='+yap+'&onay='+ona+'&odeme='+ode+'&teslim='+tes+'</cfoutput>','page');
}
```

The problem is that this link doesnt work in FF but work in IE, but if i change the function into something like this:

```
<a href="javascript://" onClick="<cfoutput>windowopen('#request.self#?fuseaction=objects2.popup_sale_propose&print=true#page_code#','page')</cfoutput"><img src="/images/print.gif" title="Gönder" border="0"></a>
```

it perfectly works in all the browsers.. i think that the problem is in defining the values of the functions, the FF just doesnt understand them...
btw, the system is Workcube and it uses the Cold Fusion.

Comment: Can you post the HTML output of the function? And also post windowpen function, And why the evals? And why create arrays which are overwritten with single strings? Or did you just miss the [i] behind kon, yap, ona, ode and tes?

Comment: Also you mix document.getElementById and document.list_basket (form access) If for example your form elements do not have ID="..." but only NAME="..." then IE will work but Fx will not since you use getElementById and not getElementsByName(...)[0]

Comment: here u can have a look, but it doesnt work since the page itself works on coldfusion: http://jsfiddle.net/QVVB7/

Comment: Please open the javascript console in firefox and look there for errors

Comment: Where is function commaSplit, function filterNum ??? We need to see the HTML output of the CF as in view-source from your browser

Comment: @mplungjan console says: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80540006 [nsIStreamListener.onDataAvailable]"  nsresult: "0x80540006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://dmbar/content/lib/tracingListener.js :: anonymous :: line 75"  data: no]

Comment: Yuck. That is something completely different. it may have nothing to do with your current page so again, can we see a page on the web somewhere???

Comment: @mplungjan did u have a look at the jsfiddle? the whole code is there actually

Comment: No it is not - have a search for filterNum and commaSplit. It is not what the browser sees! I do not have CF nor your databases so I cannot render the CF you posted

Comment: Still not enough information to help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is utterly wrong in more ways than I can count here.

Have such thing instead:

```
var satirsayisi = parseInt(document.getElementById("row_count").value, 10); 

var amntArr = new Array();
var prcArr = new Array();
var kdvArr = new Array();

var kon = document.getElementById('konu').value;
var yap = document.getElementById('yapan').value;
var ona = document.getElementById('onay').value;
var ode = document.getElementById('odeme').value;
var tes = document.getElementById('teslim').value;

for (i = 0; i < satirsayisi; i++)
{   
    amntArr.push(document.getElementById('amount' + (i+1)).value);
    prcArr.push(document.getElementById('price' + (i+1)).value);
    kdvArr.push(document.getElementById('tax_dif' + (i+1)).value);
}

var amnt = amntArr.join(",");
var prc = prcArr.join(",");
var kdv = kdvArr.join(",");
```

This assume "row_count" is the ID of the input element with the count.

For the record, the direct reason it didn't work in FF is because it has no `document.all` stuff, you can't access DOM elements via the document directly.

Comment: i think that can be the problem, the var satirsayisi=document.list_basketww.row_count.value; can't be changed properly, because of the system structure... the fucntion u gave me doesnt work

Comment: We need to see MUCH more code. Can you give a url or something? There are possibly many more inconsistencies in your code that can give all sorts of symptoms

Comment: @venom so what *ARE* `list_basketww` and `row_count`? Please post the HTML defining them or explain better that "structure" you mentioned.

Comment: here u can have a look, but it doesnt work since the page itself works on coldfusion: http://jsfiddle.net/QVVB7

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return print_gonder();"><img src="/images/print.gif" title="Gönder" border="0"></a>
```

and add

```
return false
```

to the end of the function

---

UPDATE trying to fix some more of the bad code:

```
function print_gonder() {
    var satirsayisi=document.list_basketww.row_count.value; 
    var amnt=[];
    var prc=[];
    var kdv=[];
    var kon=[];
    var yap=[];
    var ona=[];
    var ode=[];
    var tes=[];
    for (i=0; i<satirsayisi; i++) {   
        amnt[i]=document.getElementById('amount' + (i+1)).value;
        prc[i]=filterNum(document.getElementById('price' + (i+1)).value);
        kdv[i]=document.getElementById('tax_dif' + (i+1)).value;
        kon[i]=document.getElementById('konu').value;
        yap[i]=document.getElementById('yapan').value;
        ona[i]=document.getElementById('onay').value;
        ode[i]=document.getElementById('odeme').value;
        tes[i]=document.getElementById('teslim').value;
    }
    var url = '<cfoutput>#request.self#?fuseaction=objects2.popup_sale_propose&print=true#page_code#</cfoutput>';
    url += '&amnt='+amnt+'&prc='+prc+'&kdv='+kdv+'&konu='+kon+'&yapan='+yap+'&onay='+ona+'&odeme='+ode+'&teslim='+tes;
    windowopen(url,'page');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: changed the link and added the return false in the end of the function... didn't help...

Answer (score -1):

The `onclick` may be captured by the `<img>` child and not firing correctly.  To fix, moving the event to the child element will probably work.

Try this:

```
<a href="#" >
  <img src="/images/print.gif" onClick="print_gonder();" title="Gönder" border="0">
</a>
```

Better yet, remove the `<a>` and just have the image be clickable.  Add some CSS and you're on your way.

Comment: nope, didn't help... with <a> and without... btw i didnt minus ur post ))

Comment: That is HORRIFIC - Please don't do that. What is important is to return false on the onclick so the link is not followed.

Comment: @venom - Thanks. Trying to help here.

Comment: @mplungjan - What is causing the horror? The event is handled by JS, making the <a> redundant.

Comment: 1. incorrect cursor over a clickable element (please do not suggest giving the img a style with cursor:pointer) 2. screen readers will not understand the clickable element is on an image - just to name two horrors - and why would the onclick ever be captured by the img tag??? Unless you have some framework that does that on purpose

Comment: I generally use a class called 'clickable' or 'link', and put cursor:pointer as a part of that class's definition.  I'm starting to move away from <img> tags for this and just use <span> tags with backgrounds, with sprites if possible.  Of course, I also tend to put click handler bindings in my jQuery rather than embedded in the markup, but I won't call you horrific if you don't do this.  =)